# How do I get a PHP variable from one page to 2 other pages at once?

Tags: php

So, I'm working on a new website, but it requires there to be a POST from a form made on one page, and then I set the post to a variable on another page. I want to get the variable to one more page, but I want it to automatically set on that page, what should I do?

Comment: You'll need to show us some code and explain how you make your request from start to finish so that we can help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

That's an intriguing question because PHP runs the code from the top at each request. You can store the variable inside of a `_SESSION` variable. Which will be the best bet in handling this.

For instance:

```
<?php
// initiate a session
session_start();
// set the session here
$_SESSION['index'] = $_POST['posted_value'];
```

And as long as you add `session_start()` at the top you will have access to the SESSION variables.

**NOTE:** `_SESSION` are done away after user closes your page, or initiates a new session.

Comment: So, how do i access the Variable then? Do I use the "$_SESSION['index']"?

Comment: Yes sir. Just like a normal variable.@AlexanderRayner

Comment: For instance you can `echo $_SESSION['index'];` and that will `echo` the str/int value of that variable.

Comment: @AlexanderRayner